# Getting JUL to log via log4j2 while using Maven in JUnit tests

Tags: java, maven, logging, log4j2, java.util.logging

I'm running a little test project where I want my JUL logs to be redirected and appear as log4j2 logs.
I'm using the following Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.8.0-M1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-jul</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.3</version>
</dependency>
```

To use the log4j-jul adapter, I'm supposed to set the system property `java.util.logging.manager` to `org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager`.
When I do that in my project's main method with

```
System.setProperty("java.util.logging.manager", "org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager");
```

then logging works as desired. But if I use a JUnit test (run with mvn test) that does the same, like

```
@Test
public void loggingJULTest() {
    System.setProperty("java.util.logging.manager", "org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager");
    java.util.logging.Logger julLogger = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainTest.class.getName());

    julLogger.info("Info Message from JUL");
    julLogger.severe("Severe message from JUL");
    julLogger.fine("Fine message from JUL");

}
```

then the logs appear in JUL style instead.
I tried to add the following configuration to Maven's Surefire Plugin in the pom.xml

```
<configuration>
   <systemPropertyVariables>
      <java.util.logging.manager>org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
      <buildDirectory>${project.build.directory}</buildDirectory>
   </systemPropertyVariables>
</configuration>
```

but then the test gives no output and shows a warning

```
[WARNING] Corrupted STDOUT by directly writing to native stream in forked JVM 1. See FAQ web page and the dump file[..]
```

I'm confused about about what I'm supposed to be doing here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using version `3.0.0-M5` of the `maven-surefire-plugin`, you need to add `<forkNode implementation="org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.extensions.SurefireForkNodeFactory"/>` to the `configuration`.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkNode implementation="org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.extensions.SurefireForkNodeFactory"/>
                ...
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Details: [According to the Jira issue SUREFIRE-1614](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1614)

---

P.S.: In the future for similar questions, please add version information for Java and Maven.